# Powershell Invoke-Webrequest for page login when no forms are present

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315004/powershell-invoke-webrequest-no-form-in-response) without a solution but my problem is similar. I'm trying to automate some information lookup on my own login page for a service I'm using. When I run the following command it doesn't give me anything for `.Forms`

```
$Webpage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://mypage.tokyu-ps.jp/member/"
```

`$Webpage.Forms` is empty. As almost every single suggestion on doing login forms with `Invoke-WebRequest` says that I need to use `$Webpage.Forms[0]` and then enter the values there, I'm thinking I could use the `InputFields` instead.

If I check `$Webpage.InputFields` there are two fields that look like they should be the login information with the Id of `TAccountLoginid` and `TAccountPass`, however only the latter has a property called "value" which I suspect is the property I would want to set. TAccountLoginid doesn't have a value property, even when inspecting the page with F12 in my browser. (**EDIT:** It wasn't necessary this time but for future reference, you can always add your own properties with `($Webpage.InputFields | Where-Object{$_.name -eq "ItemYouWantToEdit"}) | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "value" -NotePropertyValue "Your value here"` to force it to have that for later use.)

There is one other field that looks like it could be used which is `TokenDebug0123456789` that I guess is the session token, but it already has a value of random data with `TAccount.loginid` and `TAccount.pass` mixed in there, so I guess I still need to find the field that takes the account name, then set the account name and password in the above fields, then call `Invoke-Webrequest` again using that edited `$Webpage` variable. I just don't know how to proceed in this situation.

Comment: `plaintext passwords in 2022` are OK as your connection is secured with `httpS`

Comment: So do you still have any problem? If not, please close your question.

Comment: Sure, but the Invoke-Webrequest failed unless I added -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication so I'm not sure this is all fine regardless. No I don't have any more problems, I solved it, posted the solution as an answer.

Comment: But `AllowUnencryptedAuthentication` works only for non-https connections

Comment: That's what I thought too, which is why I think the connection isn't actually using HTTPS even though it looks like it. This is a Japanese homepage after all so anything goes (read: the only security I've seen here is security by obscurity, aka not security at all). I guess it could be some form of self-signed certificate? I know too little about these things though :/ All I know is that the Invoke-Webrequest just returned the login page when using it as is but returned my actual "My Page" when using -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem while inspecting the traffic using developer tools in my browser. There were no forms present because they were sending the password in the request body. What I did was just copy the body and replace everything with the session information:

```
$Username = "MyUser"
$Password = "MyPassword"
$Webpage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://mypage.tokyu-ps.jp/member/" -SessionVariable MySession

$Body = @{
    "data[_Token][key]" = ($Webpage.InputFields | Where-Object{$_.name -eq "data[_Token][key]"}).value
    "data[TAccount][loginid]" = $Username
    "data[TAccount][pass]" = $Password
    "login" = ""
    "nextUrl" = ""
    "data[_Token][fields]" = ($Webpage.InputFields | Where-Object{$_.name -eq "data[_Token][fields]"}).value
    "data[_Token][unlocked]" = ($Webpage.InputFields | Where-Object{$_.name -eq "data[_Token][unlocked]"}).value
    "data[_Token][debug]" = ($Webpage.InputFields | Where-Object{$_.name -eq "data[_Token][debug]"}).value
}

$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri "https://mypage.tokyu-ps.jp/member/" -Body $Body -WebSession $MySession -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication
```