# Use login credentials for web page with Invoke-WebRequest when no forms or request body are present

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I had a [similar situation before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74050080/powershell-invoke-webrequest-for-page-login-when-no-forms-are-present) that was solved by adding a `-Body` to `Invoke-WebRequest`, but this time is different.

I'm using `Invoke-WebRequest` to log in to an internal document system to fetch the most recent version of a PDF file. This document is hidden behind a login form on a wordpress page that only requires a password, no username. Using developer tools in my browser when I log in normally I can see that the order of operations is this:

- Open the webpage "https://www.mypage.com/internal" with a GET request
- Send a POST request to "https://www.mypage.com/wplogin.php?action=postpass" with the following body (that always return an HTTP status code 302)

  ```
  post_password="my password here"  
  Submit="Enter"
  ```
- Directly after this, do a GET again on the https://www.mypage.com/internal which this time returns the correct contents

When I try to do this in Powershell I only get the login page. Code so far:

```
$URL = "https://www.mypage.com/internal"
$InitialRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -SessionVariable MySession -Method Get

$Body = @{
    post_password="my password here"
    Submit="Enter"
}

$LoginRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.mypage.com/wp-login.php?action=postpass" -WebSession $MySession -Body $Body -Method Post
$PageContents = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.mypage.com/internal" -WebSession $MySession -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get
```

Both `$InitialRequest` as well as `$PageContents` just give me the top level login page. While there are no `.Forms` present, there are `.InputFields` which match the parameters in the body (post_password and Submit) but I'm thinking that the 302 redirection is what messes up the request. There are no input fields that have the name Token either so it doesn't look like that would be useful either.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: HTTP Request depending on the tool that generates the request uses different default HTTP headers.  When one application works and another doesn't work the HTTP headers need to be modified.  In this case is may be the PROXY needs to be enable or disabled.  You could have a cookie issue that you need to add a cookie. HTTPS encrypts the HTTP headers.  What I sometimes do is use a sniffer like WireShark or Fiddler and capture the working request and see what headers are being used.  If encrypted I use HTTP ( not HTTPS) to capture the headers.

Comment: Ah, good info, I didn't think about proxy before, I'll look into that! I did see that the POST request both sends and receives a cookie so that could very well be it too. I don't think HTTP is enabled on this site but I'll verify your suggestions and see if it works!